# React native how to create a pdf inside a card?

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

Can anyone help me to create the above design in react native.

I am using react-native-pdf library but I could not find a way to implement above design.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should not have to load all the PDFs in card lists.

The proper way should be to use thumbnails of PDF files to show the PDF previews and when the user selects the Card then we can show the PDF Content to the user.

Here below I will suggest you have a try using the below NPM package which might workaround for your requirement.

[React Native PDF Thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-thumbnail)

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely have a look at it.